# Stop firing event tab select index changing while switching to different tab based on condition?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have application with three TabPage in tab control while switching tab I am checking condition any new control is added in the tab page if yes it has to stop going to the next tab index (which means it should not fire the event tab select Index Changed event). How to do this programmatically?

Comment: Are you saying the **user** shouldn't be able to click on another tag page if the condition is true?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud you are sure he is talking about winforms?

Comment: @WiiMaxx, I don't guess I can be sure so I'll remove the tag, but I guess we'll see.

Comment: Handle the `TabControl.Selecting` event, and check your condition for a valid tab page here. Cancel with the event args if invalid.

Comment: You can use a flag to suppress the actual code in the SelectedIndexChanged event handler from being executed. Using flag can be applied in many other similar cases. I love it ^_^

Comment: Yes i have done it through Tabconrol.selecting and based on condition i used e.cancel to retain to the same tabpage